# Export shipping table of rates programmatically with Mage API

Tags: php, magento, mage

I am trying to export the table of rates setup in magento 1.7.0.2 - essentially what I want to do is export the contents of the table shipping_tablerate via the Mage API (rather than creating my own SQL connection)

Does anyone have any idea?

Ideally I would also like to be able to add records to this table via the Mage API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function in the API.
However, you can create your own function for that:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html